# Capitalize first letter of each word using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to format words in Excel sheets using VBA such that first letter is capitalized followed by small letters in each word?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`PROPER` function should help. See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PROPER-function-52a5a283-e8b2-49be-8506-b2887b889f94) for details.

**Using VBA**

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")  'change Sheet3 to data sheet
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cel In .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.Proper(cel.Value)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**Using Formula**

```
=PROPER(A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mrig. I tried applying the Formula, but it results into formatting all the letters into smaller one's...

Comment: @JayyM - I've tested my solution, see image for reference. Can you share the screen shot of how are you using formula.

Comment: @JayyM - Instead of `Cells(i + 1, 2).Value` use `Application.Proper (Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)`

Comment: @JayyM - Or, instead of `Application.Proper` try `WorksheetFunction.Proper`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is the top Stack Overflow hit on Google for this question:

"vba code to capitalise the first letter of a word"

This code works in Office 365 Excel on Windows 10:

```
Public Function fnProperCase(sWord As String) As String
    fnProperCase = StrConv(sWord, vbProperCase)
End Function
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU12g.png) is the Excel with a test suit; row 5 has all three outputs; **test data** in col 1, `=fnProperCase()` in col 2 and `=PROPER()` in col 3

Below are various other answers on Stack Overflow and elsewhere:

[StrConv](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/strconv-function-19c3816f-dbc9-4adf-891c-fd32734c92e0)

[Capitalise first letter of words without changing currently Capitalised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471146/capitalise-first-letter-of-words-without-changing-currently-capitalised)

[Making wrong code look wrong](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/)

Answer (score 0):

This is known as **Proper Case**. You can use the following line to convert a cell value to proper case:

```
YourCell.Value = StrConv(YourCell.Value, vbProperCase)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @dotNET . My code is like: 'If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
            flag = True
                NameCity.Controls("TextBoxName").Value = Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
                NameCity.Controls("TextBoxCity").Value = Cells(i + 1, 3).Value'